# why kendo.web.min.js and kendo.dataviz.min.js conflicts?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, sparklines

I own a construction grid kendo.web.min.js with kendo.dataviz.min.js, but when I use the Using both collision occurs.

But it is interesting that the project jsfiddle it works well but when I run the project visual studio
I encountered the following error TypeError: s is undefined

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/psot98/hRJfv/32/)

[image]

```
<link href="css/themes.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="js/kendo/src/styles/kendo.dataviz.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="js/kendo/styles/kendo.silver.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="js/kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="js/kendo/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo/js/kendo.dataviz.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo/src/js/kendo.dataviz.sparkline.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

They conflict because they include the same files - kendo.data.js, kendo.core.js etc. You should never include them in the same page - use kendo.all.min.js or create a JavaScript file with only the required features.

More info is available in the Kendo UI documentation - [JavaScript dependencies](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/javascript-dependencies).

Comment: I've used kendo.all.min.js
 But the problem is because I no longer view sparklines               ** <script src="js/kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo/src/js/kendo.dataviz.sparkline.js"></script>**

Comment: Why when I use the kendo.all.min.js Sparklines does not work anymore?

Answer (score 0):

DataViz script must be put before the Web script.

```
<script src="js/kendo/js/kendo.dataviz.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/kendo/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>
```